# Show scrollbars for Absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've searched a lot on Stackoverflow but seems people want to get rid of the scroll bars , not like me , I have absolutely positioned elements and want scroll bars to be visible when the window is smaller than that positioned element

example: http://jsfiddle.net/U4kX5/2/
I want the browser scroll bars to be **VISIBLE** when the window edge reaches the **RED** box, but keep the blue one lower part hidden (so I gave the body overflow:hidden)

```html
<div class="wrapper"> 
    <div class="inner"> </div>
    <div class="partially-hidden"> </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```css
body {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.wrapper {
   position: absolute;
   bottom:0px;
   left:50%;
}
.inner {
    position:relative;
    left:-50%;
    background: red;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
.partially-hidden {
    width:100px;
    height:600px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -400px;
}
```

Comment: showing scrollbars: `overflow:scroll` - however if you have two elements inside one container and want the one hidden and the other scroll, this won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out using CSS media queries :)

just set the media screen with max height the same as the red box then changed it's position to :relative with margin:0 auto;

example: http://jsfiddle.net/U4kX5/5/

```
@media screen and (max-height:300px) { 
    .wrapper {
        position:relative;
        right:0;
        left:0;
        overflow-y:hidden;
    }

    .inner
    {
        position:relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        right:0;
        left:0;
    }

    .partially-hidden {
        left: 50%;
    }


    body {
        overflow:visible;
    }
}
```

The result is about 98% satisfying

I hope that helps any other one.

thanks.